# can someone tell me why is it deleting the whole Calendar list instead of only deleting the one with the condition?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

so here is the code there is no compiling errors or anything but it just deletes the whole cur->calendar .

```
void DeleteAtPosition(Appointment* head, int pos) {
    Appointment* cur = head->next;
    Appointment* prev = head;
    int i = 1;
    if (isEmptylist(head)) {
        cout << "LIST IS EMPTY" << endl;
    }
    if (pos == 0) {
        delete head;
        head = cur;
    }
    while (i < pos && cur->next != NULL) {
        cur = cur->next;
        prev = prev->next;
        i++;
    }
    prev->next = cur->next;
    delete cur;
}


void cancel(Company* c, string title) {
    
    Employee* cur = c->head;
    Appointment* curr=cur->Calendar;
    int pos = 0;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        while (cur->Calendar != NULL) {
            if (cur->Calendar->Title == title) {
                DeleteAtPosition(curr, pos);
            }
            pos++;
            cur->Calendar = cur->Calendar->next;
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

as u can see the code seems pretty normal and I believe the delete function is right so the problem might be in the cancel function ?

Comment: When attempting to debug things like lists, my suggestion is to always do it with the help of not only a debugger but also pencil and paper. First of all create the smallest and simplest list you can that cause the wrong behavior. Then draw this list up on paper, labeled boxes for nodes and arrows for links and other pointers. Then as you step through your code you erase and redraw arrows as you update links and pointers. Doing this kind of "visual" debugging can help find out problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes lol I actually did that yesterday and spent like few hours trying to find out whats the problem but I just couldnt find it so I kinda gave up

Comment: `cur->Calendar = cur->Calendar->next` seems wrong. Shouldn't it be something like `curr = curr->next`? Be careful when `curr` is removed and deleted though, as then you can't dereference `curr`.

Comment: bro can you try to write for me because I tried and its still not working so I really have no idea what to do

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside that function. There is nothing special about pointers. Your `pos == 0` case is broken.

Comment: @molbdnilo okay but how can I fix it tho?